# Calculating MFT for NTFS based Dynamic vhd

Tags: ntfs, disk-image, vhd, mft, vhdx

I am trying to calculate MFT offset from master boot section of NTFS filesystem of Dynamic VHD. The Little Endian cluster location of this Dynamic VHD MFT is highlighted:

[image: ntfs]

which is then further resolved to `MFT_OFFSET= cluster_address * sector_per_cluster * SECTORSIZE` (here `SECTORSIZE` is 512) to calculate actual offset of MFT... This calculation works in case of Fixed VHD. But in Dynamic VHD it's not.

In Dynamic I have the Block Allocation table values. The first entry I have used to calculate the disk MBR which then points me to first partition of disk. Here I am able to calculate MBS offset. But when I used the above mentioned cluster location to calculate MFT location, it's pointing to somewhere else.

What are further steps that can help me with this?

Comment: I have never bothered with it, this might be nice introduction https://redcircle.blog/2008/12/01/dynamic-vhd-walkthrough/

Comment: "it's pointing to somewhere else." - Yes, the way I read it you need to resolve that using the BAT again. It adds an additional translation layer. https://learn-attachment.microsoft.com/api/attachments/133889-image.png?platform=QnA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Dynamic I have the Block Allocation table values. The first entry I
> have used to calculate the disk MBR which then points me to first
> partition of disk. Here I am able to calculate MBS offset. But when I
> used the above mentioned cluster location to calculate MFT location,
> it's pointing to somewhere else.

Yes, because you again need to resolve the extra translation step. If we assume:

[image]

then according how I read various documents I Googled (example: https://redcircle.blog/2008/12/01/dynamic-vhd-walkthrough/), we have an added translation layer to overcome:

Cluster > LBA if we're dealing with a drive. Since you're not relying on the OS or a file system driver you need to resolve steps 1 - 5 in Normal DISK I/O example yourself.

Cluster > LBA and then LBA > Block inside VHD. Since you're not relying on the OS or a file system driver you need to resolve steps 1 - 9 in Dynamic VHD I/O example yourself.

You resolved the MBR following these steps, you have to do the same for position of the MFT. And you can't just assume that once you translated position of the MBR that from that point on you can just 'count' as:

"Also, never assume that the sector offsets are in a row.  A dump of the offsets reveal that they can be scrambled up." - from page I linked to earlier.

IOW, each sector you want to read you'll have to look up in the 'BAT'.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation here. But after translating MFT location, I could see that all the MFTs are also not in contiguous location . Few are in contiguous and few are again in some other offset.  I could deduce the first MFT location using "MFT_OFFSET= cluster_address * sector_per_cluster * SECTORSIZE" and then adding extra translational formula to get first MFT location. Later on since each MFT block is 1024 bytes, next few MFT and stored in contiguous location of 1024 bytes. But not all. I could only see few files in this order...How to deduce the next MFT  offset?

Comment: I am no expert on VHD's but the MFT records not being a contiguous 'block' seems to match my answer and what I read.